# restore dynamically created javascript table structure after asp.net button post back

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, updatepanel, postback

On runtime i am creating table structure using javascript and appending it to the div which is placed in an update panel. Problem here is, when i use asp.net button control, onClick of the button it posts the page to server and whatever javascript tables i have created it goes off. When i use html input button (input type="button") i don't face this problem and tables also stay there. But i have to use asp.net button to take necessary actions on the server side. 
Is there any way that i can restore the structure or use asp.net button control alongwith dynamic javascript. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Move your server side logic into Page Method,use html button and then  call that method using ajax.

Comment: yea but it has lot of work around to do right. At present doing the way you said but it becomes unmanageable at times in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save your table structure in an `Hidden` field just before clicking/submitting on asp.net button. On Post back, you can redisplay that. The asp.net button has property 
[OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx), you can use this property.

Comment: ok, so i need to store table object in hidden field. then how can i recreate that table structure.

Comment: @mehul9595 Save the table structure (html markup) you created through JavaScript, should be saved in a hidden field. Mark the hidden field with `runat="server"`, so on posting a form, it is available and if you want to regenerate(probably due to validation error etc) you can do so.

Comment: i got the solution you suggested. As you said, i am storing the table ojbect in globally declared variable inside javascript and on endRequest of UpdatePanel i am again creating the table. It is working fine for me in mozilla and safari but, when i tested it in IE 8 got to know that globally decalred var was not storing any value. Do you know why this is happening?